# AngularJS: several tabs open, only one should run specific function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I’m not sure if this is possible at all, but what I’m trying to do is have an AngularJS app that stores some data in localStorage so that all tabs running the app can access the shared data. I’d also like to be able to automatically update that data via the $http service with setInterval().

Both those bits are easy enough.

The problem is that the user might open up the app in multiple tabs, and all of the tabs that are running the app will attempt to update the shared data, whereas what I’d like to do is have just one of the tabs acting as the "master", and only that tab runs the update function.

So the process should go like this:

1. Open the app in first tab
2. Check if tab is the only one running the app (Assume this is true for this example)
3. First tab becomes "master"
4. Wait for 10 minutes, then first tab runs update function
5. Open a second tab running the same app
6. Check if tab is the only one running the app (It isn’t, so this is false)
7. Wait for 10 minutes, both tabs attempt to run the update function but only the first one updates the data as it’s the one set to "master"
8. First tab is closed by the user
9. Second tab checks if it’s the only one running the app (it is now, so this is true)
10. Second tab (or any other tab that’s open) becomes "master"

Is there any way of achieving this in AngularJS or in a generic Javascript way? Does this even make sense?

Thanks

Comment: Would "Set the tabs 'unique id' on the local storage on 'activate', run timer in both which checks own id == localstorage.activetabid. if same=>update data)" be possible?

Comment: That’s given me an idea as to how I can do it, but I think in a less complicated way to how I originally thought about it. I’ve set a timestamp in local storage for when the last update occurred, then every tab checks when it was last updated an if it was more than 10 mins ago it runs the update. I’ve changed the update setInterval() to run every 60 seconds, so all the tabs have a chance of running the update and it doesn’t really matter which one does as long as it doesn’t hit the server too often!